# How to establish SIP connection, when SIP-proxy is required?

Tags: voip, asterisk

I have

```
Asterisk/1.8.13.1
Asterisk GUI-version : SVN--r
```

Yes, quite old one, but I can not update it since this is installed on my Synology NAS. NAS is connected to internet thru router Asus RT-N16.

I should use the following data to connect to the server:

- Auth name – 7499952XXXX
- User name/User ID/Display Name – nickname
- Authorization user name - 7499952XXXX@sip.beeline.ru
- Domain - sip.beeline.ru
- SIP proxy server - msk.sip.beeline.ru

I've also found the following string:

```
nickname@sip.beeline.ru:password:7499952XXXX@sip.beeline.ru@msk.sip.beeline.ru:5060/7499952XXXX
```

I've tested the parameters on my PC thru X-Lite and it works well (so, assume there is no any problem with the router, no need to do anything with router's NAS settings).

But since I am quite new to Asterisk, I can not understand where to input all these data. Asterisk GUI doesn't have fields for proxy:
[image: Asterisk GUI]

Can somebody please help me with step-by-step instruction? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest leaving the FromDomain and FromUser empty.  Try it like this:

- Username: 7499952XXXX@sip.beeline.ru
- Hostname: msk.sip.beeline.ru